# How to Change Footer Copyright Text in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, theme, footer

I want to customize `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer` class in magento2.

how can i change some text and style of footer copyright text with custom module..

Answer (score 13):

***You don't need to create custom module. You can change the copyright text in Admin.***

1. *Go to Content >> Configuration.*
2. *Edit the active theme*
3. *Click on Footer tab*
4. *Edit the copyright Text*
   [image]

**OR**

You can override Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer class in your custom module with `getCopyright` function like this:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Theme\Block\Html;

class Footer extends Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer
{
    /*
     * Retrieve copyright information
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCopyright()
    {
        if (!$this->_copyright) {
            $this->_copyright = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/footer/copyright',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            );
        }
        return __($this->_copyright);
    }

}
```

and update the getCopyright function as per your requirement.

If you can specify the exact requirement as to what needs to be changed I can help you in better way.

Comment: I know this method..but my concern is from `Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer` this class with custom module

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer you need:

Create your own module.

Create YourVendor/YourModule/etc/frontend/di.xml file like:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" type="YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Html\Footer" />
```

Create your block like:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Html;

/**
 * Html page footer block
 */
class Footer extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer
{
   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
    public function getCopyright(): string
    {
        $copyright = parent::getCopyright();

        return '| ' . $copyright . ' |';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create di.xml file in <vendor_name>/<module_name>/etc/frontend ***(i.e Lokesh/Custom/etc/frontend/di.xml)***

   ```
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" type="Lokesh\Custom\Block\Html\Footer" />
    </config>
   ```
2. Create Footer.php in <vendor_name>/<module_name>/Block/Html ***(i.e Lokesh/Custom/Block/Html/Footer.php)*** and add below code

**A. Without Template**:

```
<?php
namespace Lokesh\Custom\Block\Html;

class Footer extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer
{
     public function getCopyright()
    {
        if (!$this->_copyright) {
            $this->_copyright = "Your Copyright Content goes here";
        }
        return __($this->_copyright);
    }
}
```

**B. With Template**:

```
<?php
namespace Lokesh\Custom\Block\Html;

class Footer extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer
{
     public function getCopyright()
    {
        if (!$this->_copyright) {
            $this->_copyright =  $this->getLayout()
          ->createBlock('Lokesh\Custom\Block\Html\Footer')
          ->setTemplate('Lokesh_Custom::footer.phtml')
          ->toHtml();

        }
        return __($this->_copyright);
    }

    public function getYear()
    {
        return date('Y');
    }
}
```

Template File: ***Lokesh/Custom/view/template/footer.phtml***

```
<?php
$year = $block->getYear();
?>
<p class="copyright col-m-6">Copyright © <?= $year; ?> Company and Content</p>
```

**NOTE:** Execute `php bin/magento cache:flush` and `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` in cli to see the changes on storefront

Answer (score 0):

To Add a dynamic year in the footer copyright section use this mobile under System -> Configuration -> Design. Ability to show a year variable via the Theme Footer configuration

**Here is a module used this year that will change dynamically. Even the PWA app year will change if you use this extension in Magento PWA.**

https://github.com/niraligajera/magento-CopyRightFooter